# Transfering data between applications in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I wonder whether the following can be done in Worklight: We have two mobile apps. When we click on a button in app A, something is calculated using parameter X from app B, there it is an input field. Namely the user can change X in app B and it will affect the calculation results for app A.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this:

- Application A sends X to a backend (possibly via a Worklight Adapter).
- Application B requests X from a backend (possibly via a Worklight Adapter).

There no Worklight API that I can think of for doing this without a server.

Possibly related:

*"Android implements a few key tools used to communicate with or coordinate between programs securely. These mechanisms give Android applications the ability to run processes in the background, offer services consumed by other applications, safely share relational data, start other programs, and reuse components from other applications safely."* - [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396547/186909)

*"iOS apps have several options for sharing data amongst themselves via Inter-Process Communication (IPC). App-to-app sharing of chemical data is described in detail."* - [Read more here](http://molmatinf.com/ipcappios.html)